# Why not replace the [mp3-player] tag with, for example, [audio-player]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tagging

Most of the devices that get called "mp3 players" in reality do play **several audio formats.**

Also, MP3 is nowadays the most ineffective if compared to popular alternatives (Vorbis, Opus, AAC) due to its technological limitations. And it's also patent-encumbered. So there's almost zero practical reason for getting a device that really supports only MP3. (do they even exist anymore?)

FSF also thinks it's more correct/accurate to call them "audio players": https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/words-to-avoid.en.html#MP3Player

Answer (score 5):

"MP3 player" is common vernacular. If someone asks a question about an "MP3 player", I don't think a knowledgeable answer is going to contain a product that *only* plays the MP3 format.

Additionally, if you search ["audio player amazon"](https://www.google.com/search?q=audio%20player%20amazon), the search results include the following:

- [MP3 Players & Accessories: Electronics - Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/MP3-Players-Audio-Video/b/ref=nav_shopall_mp3?ie=UTF8&node=172630)
- [MP3 Players: Electronics](http://www.amazon.com/MP3-Players-Portable-Audio-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=1264866011)
- [Amazon Best Sellers: Best MP3 Players - Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1264866011)

Plus many links to places to download music across Amazon's ecosystem

Searching for ["audio player newegg"](https://www.google.com/search?q=audio%20player%20newegg) returns:

- [MP3 / MP4 Players - Newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/MP3-MP4-Players/SubCategory/ID-23)
- [Panasonic Pro Digital USB50 Audio Player](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA19P1C80045) (I bet this isn't what you mean when you say "audio player")

---

"MP3 player" is the generic term for such a device. I think the tag should remain as it is.

Comment: I personally find it disappointing that the "MP3" terminology stuck because I'm an audio geek. But alas, it's the most correct term to use still. "Audio player" could refer to a multitude of things.